# Proporções de uma imagem redimensionada com OpenCV?

Tags: c++, imagem, processamento-de-imagens, opencv, redimensionamento

Estou com um projeto onde preciso identificar objetos em uma imagem, atualmente estou utilizando a biblioteca OpenCV em C++. Utilizei a função `warpPerspective()` do OpenCV em uma imagem de tamanho 605x141 para redimensionar sua perspectiva para uma imagem com tamanho 674x35. Ao fazer isso o objeto da imagem foi distorcido como na ilustração de Exemplo na imagem abaixo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Digamos que a largura do objeto na primeira imagem seja 100, por exemplo. Como posso identificar a nova largura do objeto na nova imagem distorcida? Parece óbvio mas tentei utilizar regra de três básica, utilizando a área e a razão de aspecto das duas imagens, porém o resultado não está batendo quando comparo manualmente a largura em um editor de imagens.

Obs: Caso esta pergunta não seja compatível com alguma política do fórum, por favor me avisem para que eu possa tentar reformulá-la.

**EDIT:**

Não sei exatamente se irá auxiliar para a resolução do problema, mas eis abaixo o código onde realizo a transformação de perspectiva:

```
void MyClass::TransformPerspec(){

Mat mat = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_8UC1);
this->fileira = cvCreateMat(35, 674, CV_8UC1); // matriz de saida da fileira será de tamanho 674x35

// Input Quadilateral or Image plane coordinates
Point2f inputQ[4];
// Output Quadilateral or World plane coordinates
Point2f outputQ[4];

inputQ[0].x = this->X1; inputQ[0].y = this->Y1;
inputQ[1].x = this->X2; inputQ[1].y = this->Y2;
inputQ[2].x = this->X3; inputQ[2].y = this->Y3;
inputQ[3].x = this->X4; inputQ[3].y = this->Y4;

outputQ[0].x = 0 ; outputQ[0].y = 0;
outputQ[1].x = 674;outputQ[1].y = 0;
outputQ[2].x = 0;  outputQ[2].y = 35;
outputQ[3].x = 674;outputQ[3].y = 35;

mat = getPerspectiveTransform(inputQ, outputQ);
warpPerspective(this->imagem_proc, this->fileira, mat, this->fileira.size());

imwrite("Teste.bmp", this->fileira);

}
```

Após a transformação de perspectiva eu apenas chamo este método:

```
reconheceObject(int largura);
```

onde eu utilizo a largura do objeto da primeira imagem para o reconhecimento, mas como o objeto é distorcido após a transformada de perspectiva, o valor de 'largura' precisa ser recalculado com base na nova imagem. Por isto inicialmente pensei que poderia utilizar uma regra de três para encontrar a nova largura. Porém agora sei que uma possível solução não é tão simples.

Comment: Qual o valor retornado pela regra de 3, e qual o valor que está sendo retornado "manualmente" ? A diferença e muito grande ? Obs. mais como curiosidade, não conheço OpenCV.

Comment: Na imagem redimensionada, contando manualmente, o valor da largura é 120. Realizando a regra de tres pela razao de aspecto, tenho L = (19,26*100)/4,29 = 448. Utilizando a regra de tres pela área das imagens, tenho: L = (23590*100)/85305 = 27,65. Os valores de largura resultante sao completamente diferentes, nao chegam nem a se aproximar. Quando analiso a imagem redimensionada, a largura fica 120. :/ Obrigado por responder.

Comment: Vc *não pode* usar regra de 3 para isso, porque a sua operação não mantém proporção. Pelo contrário, você está aplicando uma transformação de perspectiva na imagem (é como se você tivesse "deitado" a imagem original e estivesse olhando a bola de outra posição).

Comment: Honestamente eu não sei a resposta, mas suponho que você possa usar a fórmula que [consta na documentação](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpPerspective(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue)) **com a mesma matriz de transformação** que você aplicou na imagem. Deve ser possível assim "mapear" as coordenadas dos cantos da bola da imagem original para a nova imagem, e aí então é só medir as dimensões entre essas novas coordenadas.

Comment: Por outro lado, dependendo de como é o fundo e o objeto (a bola) da imagem, talvez seja simplesmente mais fácil você segmentá-lo novamente (ou somente) na imagem transformada. Eu sugeriria que você editasse a pergunta para postar um exemplo de código, um [mcve] se possível. Facilita que alguém se interesse em te ajudar.

Comment: A transformaçao de perspectiva estou utilizando apenas para poder tornar a imagem proxima de uma imagem padrão para objetos na diagonal. A bola deitada seria na verdade os seus lados que deformaram para os lados, pois a imagem na verdade foi achatada. Organizarei meu codigo e postarei na pergunta para que facilite o entendimento do meu problema. Obrigado.

Comment: "A transformaçao de perspectiva estou utilizando apenas para poder tornar a imagem proxima de uma imagem padrão para objetos na diagonal." Esse é o tipo de coisa que se faz em arte e design, não no uso computacional de imagens. Se você altera a imagem apenas para ela "parecer mais bacana", você só dificulta o seu trabalho de segmentação.

Comment: A transformaçao de perspectiva é para consertar o angulo de rotaçao do objeto que estou identificando. Imagine que eu tenho uma imagem intera com varios objetos enfileirados na diagonal. A transformaçao de perspectiva é para corrigir essa diferença de angulaçao para que eu possa identificar os objetos de forma linear na imagem. Quando eu arrumo a perspectiva, eu gravo a imagem rotacionada nessa de 674x35. O problema é q preciso identificar a largura do objeto na imagem transformada q é onde estou com problemas. Pois a nova imagem está modificando a representaçao do objeto.

Comment: Logo mais editarei meu post com o codigo da perspectiva. Para tentar esclarecer melhor o problema.

Comment: Sim, eu entendi Yuri. Eu só não entendi por que você acha que precisa alinhar os objetos de forma diferente para que seja possível identificá-los. Enfim, isso é outro problema. A sua pergunta original é como fazer para calcular a dimensão de um objeto após uma operação de warp. A minha dica foi dada (só não respondi porque não tenho certeza se funciona). Agora, se tudo isso vai ser útil ou não é outro problema. Só tentei dar a dica adicional de que talvez vc esteja complicando algo que não é necessário ser complicado. Enfim, é isso aí. Boa sorte.

Comment: Obrigado @LuizVieira, estava relutante em postar o código porque o projeto está imenso no momento, e achei que seria mais uma questão de lógica que nao estava conseguindo ver. Darei uma olhada na documentação do opencv para buscar algumas alternativas. Obrigado!

Comment: A biblioteca OpenCV não possui métodos(funções) que retornam os parâmetros (altura, largura, etc) da imagem, diretamente ? Será que realmente é preciso calcular os parâmetros da imagem modificada ? De repente é só uma questão de se utilizar adequadamente dos recursos da própria OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

Viva, penso que estás a precisar da função **resize(src,dst,size)**, onde a src é a tua imagem original e a dst é uma nova variável de imagem que vais criar e size é o tamanho da imagem final que podes declarar assim: **Size size(100,100)**.

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SOPT. Sei que você ainda não tem reputação suficiente pra comentar, mas os campos de resposta só devem ser utilizados para dar uma resposta direta à pergunta. Sugestões e questionamentos devem ser dados em comentários.

Answer (score 1):

Para manter as proporções da imagem original sem que haja distorções você só pode escolher arbitrariamente o tamanho de uma das novas dimensões, a outra dimensão irá aumentar ou diminuir de acordo com a mudança que houve na dimensão escolhida, sendo assim, se a sua imagem possui altura 100 e você deseja aumenta-la para 140 (crescimento de 40%), sua nova largura deverá ser 40% maior. Isso é válido para a escolha de ambas as dimensões. O seguinte trecho de código dá uma ideia de como resolver.

```
    double novaLargura = antigaLargura * novaAltura / antigaAltura;
    resize(img, img, Size(novaLargura, novaAltura));
```